# Need to filter a object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a object

```
course = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Computer Science',
    country: 'Uinited State',
    university:{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Oxford'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'BBA',
    country: 'Uinited State',
    university:{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Starnford'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'BBA',
    country: 'Uinited State',
    university:{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Oxford'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Computer Engineering',
    country: 'Uinited State',
    university:{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Oxford'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'MBA',
    country: 'Uinited State',
    university:{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Starnford'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'ETE',
    country: 'Uinited State',
    university:{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Oxford'
    }
  }
]
```

I need to filter this object. I need to filter by university and the filter university can not be 3 length.
format like below.

```
filterData = [
  {
  uniVersityId: 1,
  data: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Computer Science',
    country: 'Uinited State',
    university:{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Oxford'
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'BBA',
    country: 'Uinited State',
    university:{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Oxford'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Computer Engineering',
    country: 'Uinited State',
    university:{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Oxford'
    }
  },
  ],
  },
  {
  uniVersityId: 2,
  data:             [{
    id: 2,
    name: 'BBA',
    country: 'Uinited State',
    university:{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Starnford'
    }
  },
    {
    id: 5,
    name: 'MBA',
    country: 'Uinited State',
    university:{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Starnford'
    }
  },
  ],
  }
```

I have started

```
course.map(course=>{
      if( !mainData.length ){
        mainData.country.name.push(course)
      }
    })
```

Need to filter the array by university. university will be a array and the university array length can not be 3. if there have more than 3 data ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not so much a filter you need, its really grouping by university name, and ensuring there is a maximum of 3 items in each group

```js
const course=[{id:1,name:"Computer Science",country:"Uinited State",university:{id:1,name:"Oxford"}},{id:2,name:"BBA",country:"Uinited State",university:{id:2,name:"Starnford"}},{id:3,name:"BBA",country:"Uinited State",university:{id:1,name:"Oxford"}},{id:4,name:"Computer Engineering",country:"Uinited State",university:{id:1,name:"Oxford"}},{id:5,name:"MBA",country:"Uinited State",university:{id:2,name:"Starnford"}},{id:6,name:"ETE",country:"Uinited State",university:{id:1,name:"Oxford"}}];

const result = Object.entries(course.reduce( (acc,i) => {
  acc[i.university.id] = acc[i.university.id] || [];
  if(acc[i.university.id].length < 3){  
    acc[i.university.id].push(i);
  }
  return acc;
},{})).map ( ([universityId,data]) => ({universityId, data}))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I have update my question on filter format and you please update your answer.

Comment: @Md.GolamRabbani done.

Answer (score -1):

```
var val = 'Oxford';

var temp= this.temp.filter((d) => {
  return d.university.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val
});
```

Comment: Why oxford as variable I have more then one university??

Comment: You want to retrieve all university values? I thought you were searching for one.

Comment: Try returning your mainData.country.name instead of adding it to external array.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.